# An incomprehensible warning

Tags: bug, questions

I was about to ask a question, when this warning appeared:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   **you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.**
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a
>   good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.
>   Title

I asked six questions and not a single one of them has scored negative. Should I ignore this warning?

Comment: For more documentation on why this happens, see [this thread on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997). The exact details of how question bans happen are kept secret to avoid people gaming the system, but looking at your (publicly visible) question record, it does look strange. The mechanism is mostly intended for a different demographic so don't take the tone + content of that link too hard - I'm mostly leaving it here for the benefit of others who hit the same snag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm... this is kind of odd. Your posting history stacks up as follows:

- One zero-score deleted question
- One zero-score deleted-and-closed question
- One zero-score migrated question
- One positive-score closed/on hold question
- One zero-score open question
- Three upvoted open questions

That seems like a perfectly reasonable set of questions to me. So I would say you should ignore the warning...

...except that this warning is part of an automated system, and not something that can be manually overridden. It indicates that you're getting close to some threshold of an overall question quality score. I don't know the formula for this score, nor the threshold, and I'm a little surprised that your questions come close to it, but regardless, if you do happen to run over the threshold, the fact that it seems strange isn't going to help you.

My advice is to keep posting, and don't take the warning as a sign that you're doing anything wrong, but just be a little bit more cautious about your next couple questions. Don't ask "risky" questions; instead, stick to asking things that you're reasonably confident will not get downvoted, and that you won't want to delete later on. Considering that none of your other questions are downvoted, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I once got this same message through an email at the beginning of activities here.

Comment: I deleted a comment thread that was getting a little argumentative. Remember not to make unjustifiable accusations.

Comment: Yes, it was going pointless after-all.

Comment: 4 out of 8 questions closed, deleted, and/or migrated does not seem like a *"perfectly reasonable set of questions to me"*.  If half your questions have to be closed or migrated, then you probably don't in fact belong here.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I strongly disagree with that, and I think it's a rather inappropriate suggestion to make - or let me be explicit, I think it's dangerously close to running afoul of our "be nice" policy. It's expected that people will accumulate some closures, migrations, and deletions as they get used to the way the site works.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I can remove my account, if my presence here offends you. Two questions were self-deleted because they got no response, and the closed one could never be answered. I have 8 questions, none with negative score, one *closed* and one on-hold on an arguable motivation. The migrated question was answered and upvoted.

Comment: @frank: You don't have to abandon this site just seeing another one talking like that; this is his opinion. You don't seem to get annoyed at that. Probably I also disagree with his argument. So, don't leave; stay here & enjoy this community:)